# Does running Import Organization twice using Same Database can cause issue in MSCRM2011?

Tags: sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012, dynamics-crm

I have been migrating MSCRM2011 from Windows Server 2008 to Windows Server 2012 & SQL Server from 2008 to 2012, facing below issue.

Steps I performed:

1. Install CRM with Demo name on new Windows Server 2012
2. Create replica of CRM DB from old SQL Server 2008 to new SQL Server 2012
3. Run Import Organization on the migrated DB

However on running Import first time by mistake the organization name was given as wrong so I reran the import to give desired name on same migrated DB. So I have ran Import twice on same CRM DB

But now I am facing issue in adding new user and getting below error, also getting below generic error:

Error:

> Unhandled Exception: System.ServiceModel.FaultException`1[[Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.OrganizationServiceFault, Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35]]: An unexpected error occurred.
>
> Detail:
>   
>   -2147220970
>   
>   An unexpected error occurred.
>   2017-08-19T06:57:35.402523Z

Below is the event viewer:

```
The Web Service plug-in failed in OrganizationId: 7bece0b8-b36e-424b-9b01-78d604765f62; SdkMessageProcessingStepId: 56f5c774-9ecb-45f2-99c2-8dd57737af6e; EntityName: none; Stage: 30; MessageName: AssociateEntities; AssemblyName: Microsoft.Crm.Extensibility.InternalOperationPlugin, Microsoft.Crm.ObjectModel, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35; ClassName: Microsoft.Crm.Extensibility.InternalOperationPlugin; Exception: Unhandled Exception: System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.
   at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Object[] arguments, Signature sig, Boolean constructor)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.UnsafeInvokeInternal(Object obj, Object[] parameters, Object[] arguments)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
   at System.Web.Services.Protocols.LogicalMethodInfo.Invoke(Object target, Object[] values)
   at Microsoft.Crm.Extensibility.InternalOperationPlugin.Execute(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
   at Microsoft.Crm.Extensibility.V5PluginProxyStep.ExecuteInternal(PipelineExecutionContext context)
   at Microsoft.Crm.Extensibility.VersionedPluginProxyStepBase.Execute(PipelineExecutionContext context)
Inner Exception: System.InvalidCastException: Specified cast is not valid.
   at Microsoft.Crm.Timeouts.GetExtendedTimeout()
   at Microsoft.Crm.ObjectModel.SystemUserBusinessUnitEntityMapUtility.ReInitMapForUsers(Guid[] systemUsers, ExecutionContext context)
   at Microsoft.Crm.ObjectModel.TeamServiceInternal`1.ReInitTeamMembers(Guid[] userIds, ReinitMasks reinitMask, ExecutionContext context)
   at Microsoft.Crm.ObjectModel.TeamMembershipServiceInternal`1.Associate(BusinessEntityMoniker entityOneMoniker, BusinessEntityMoniker entityTwoMoniker, String associationRelationshipName, ExecutionContext context)
   at Microsoft.Crm.BusinessEntities.BusinessProcessObject.HandleAssociationOperation(BusinessEntityMoniker entityOneMoniker, BusinessEntityMoniker entityTwoMoniker, String associationRelationshipName, Boolean createAssociation, ExecutionContext context)
   at Microsoft.Crm.BusinessEntities.BusinessProcessObject.AssociateEntities(BusinessEntityMoniker entityOneMoniker, BusinessEntityMoniker entityTwoMoniker, String associationRelationshipName, ExecutionContext context)
```

Traces(https://www.pastiebin.com/599da0c5497e6):

```
Web Service Plug-in failed in SdkMessageProcessingStepId: {56F5C774-9ECB-45F2-99C2-8DD57737AF6E}; EntityName: none; Stage: 30; MessageName: AssociateEntities; AssemblyName: Microsoft.Crm.Extensibility.InternalOperationPlugin, Microsoft.Crm.ObjectModel, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35; ClassName: Microsoft.Crm.Extensibility.InternalOperationPlugin; Exception: Unhandled Exception: System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.
   at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Object[] arguments, Signature sig, Boolean constructor)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.UnsafeInvokeInternal(Object obj, Object[] parameters, Object[] arguments)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
   at System.Web.Services.Protocols.LogicalMethodInfo.Invoke(Object target, Object[] values)
   at Microsoft.Crm.Extensibility.InternalOperationPlugin.Execute(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
   at Microsoft.Crm.Extensibility.V5PluginProxyStep.ExecuteInternal(PipelineExecutionContext context)
   at Microsoft.Crm.Extensibility.VersionedPluginProxyStepBase.Execute(PipelineExecutionContext context)
Inner Exception: System.InvalidCastException: Specified cast is not valid.
   at Microsoft.Crm.Timeouts.GetExtendedTimeout()
   at Microsoft.Crm.ObjectModel.SystemUserBusinessUnitEntityMapUtility.ReInitMapForUsers(Guid[] systemUsers, ExecutionContext context)
   at Microsoft.Crm.ObjectModel.TeamServiceInternal`1.ReInitTeamMembers(Guid[] userIds, ReinitMasks reinitMask, ExecutionContext context)
   at Microsoft.Crm.ObjectModel.TeamMembershipServiceInternal`1.Associate(BusinessEntityMoniker entityOneMoniker, BusinessEntityMoniker entityTwoMoniker, String associationRelationshipName, ExecutionContext context)
   at Microsoft.Crm.BusinessEntities.BusinessProcessObject.HandleAssociationOperation(BusinessEntityMoniker entityOneMoniker, BusinessEntityMoniker entityTwoMoniker, String associationRelationshipName, Boolean createAssociation, ExecutionContext context)
   at Microsoft.Crm.BusinessEntities.BusinessProcessObject.AssociateEntities(BusinessEntityMoniker entityOneMoniker, BusinessEntityMoniker entityTwoMoniker, String associationRelationshipName, ExecutionContext context)
.
```

Comment: Error log provided but it is very generic

Comment: Enable & Check in trace file

Comment: Thanks for the reply..But very beginner in CRM, can you tell me how we can do it, if required I can provide you Event viewer?

Comment: Anything useful in event viewer ?

Comment: Search in google - how to enable Trace in crm? But make sure to turn off once investigation is over..

Comment: I Deleted Demo Organization from Deployment Manager and reimported again Demo_MSCRM and there also I am facing issue which was not there. So it seems Importing twice on same DB is causing issue in adding User.

Comment: @ArunVinoth : I restore DB again and imported again, the issue is still reproducible. Need to check with CRM Traces, will provide log shortly

Comment: added eventviewer details

Comment: pls follow this: https://mayankp.wordpress.com/2010/09/11/dynamic-crm-troubleshooting-methods-for-any-crm-issue/

Comment: These tells the story - EntityName: none; Stage: 30; MessageName: AssociateEntities; Inner Exception: System.InvalidCastException: Specified cast is not valid. enable Dev errors or trace to see exact error.

Comment: @ArunVinoth: I have pasted Tracing error, however turning on dev errors is not working

Comment: did you try "Auto-map users" ref this: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn905200.aspx. are you getting for only new users? any plugins for Manager, BU, Team, etc ??

Comment: you may need to reach out to MS if your org is messed up :)

Comment: @ArunVinoth: Yes..right, Below are the steps where I am facing issue in adding new users, for existing user in changing Security role & Business Unit. Yes I auto-mapped the user. It's Dev Server if required I can reinstall CRM. Please guide

Comment: I was not able to find the resolution so we reinstall the CRM again and it is working now. Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

From comments:

Unable to find the resolution so we reinstalled the CRM and it is working now.